# Pagination not working in Codeigniter on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am new to Codeigniter. This is my first experience in Codeigniter. I have problem in pagination. I have tried lot of codes given on forums and blogs. Lastly I followed a tutorial, link: [CodeIgniter from Scratch- Day 16 - Displaying & Sorting Tabular Data - Nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-displaying-sorting-tabular-data/)

Here is my code:

**user.php**

```
public function index($offset=0)
{
    $limit  =   10;
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $results                =   $this->user_model->get_all_users($limit,$offset);
    $data['users']          =   $results['rows'];
    $data['num_results']    =   $results['num_rows'];

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config =   array();
    $config['base_url']     =   site_url('admin/user');
    $config['total_rows']   =   $data['num_results'];
    $config['per_page']     =   $limit;
    $config['uri_segment']  =   3;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $date['pagination'] =   $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['page_title'] =   "List Of Users";
    $this->load->view('admin/users', $data);
}
```

**user_model.php**

```
function get_all_users($limit, $offset)
{
    $q  =   $this->db
                    ->select('user_id,user_email,login_name,phone_num,user_status')
                    ->from('tbl_user')
                    ->limit($limit,$offset);
    $ret['rows']    =   $q->get()->result();

    $q      =   $this->db
                        ->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)
                        ->from('tbl_user');
    $tmp    =   $q->get()->result();
    $ret['num_rows']    =   $tmp[0]->count;
    return $ret;
}
```

**users.php**

```
<?php 
$this->load->view('includes/header');
$this->load->view('includes/menu-admin');
?>
<div id="container">

    <?php if(isset($users)) { ?>
            <p><?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?></p>
        <table id="users_table" class="board">
            <tr>
                <th class="blue-gradient">#</th>
                <th class="blue-gradient">Email Address</th>
                <th class="blue-gradient">Login Name</th>
                <th class="blue-gradient">User Status</th>
                <th class="blue-gradient">Current Status</th>
            </tr>
            <?php $count=1; ?>
        <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
            <tr id="user_<?php echo $user->user_id; ?>" class="darker-on-hover">
                <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo anchor('admin/profile/view/'.$user->user_id,$user->user_email , 'class="view-profile-details"'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user->login_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user->user_status; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo anchor('admin/user/edit/'.$user->user_id , '<img src="'.base_url().'images/edit.png" title="Edit User"/>'); ?>
                    <?php echo anchor('admin/user/remove/'.$user->user_id , '<img src="'.base_url().'images/remove.png" title="Remove User"/>', 'class="remove-user-event"'); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php $count++; } ?>
        </table>



    <?php } ?>

    <div id="pageNum">
        <?php if(strlen($pagination)): ?>       
            Pages: <?php echo $pagination; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if I am wrong?

Comment: what problem are you encountering?

Comment: When I click on the Next Page (i.e: http://localhost/wmss/index.php/admin/user/3) 
It shows an error 
"404 Page Not Found"
The page you requested was not found.

Comment: 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your config like this

```
$config['base_url']     =   site_url('admin/user/');
$config['total_rows']   =   $data['num_results'];
$config['per_page']     =   $limit;
$config['uri_segment']  =   3;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Please note / in site_url. It often happens that the url genetrated for pagination is like this

```
 http://localhost/myapp/index.php/admin/user10
```

Which is wrong. If you put a slash you will have correct pagination links

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.php/admin/user/10
```

EDITS :

your controller should look like this

```
Class User Extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index($offset=0)
    {
        $limit  =   10;
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $results                =   $this->user_model->get_all_users($limit,$offset);
        $data['users']          =   $results['rows'];
        $data['num_results']    =   $results['num_rows'];

        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config =   array();
        $config['base_url']     =   site_url('user/index');
        $config['total_rows']   =   $data['num_results'];
        $config['per_page']     =   $limit;
        $config['uri_segment']  =   3;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $date['pagination'] =   $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['page_title'] =   "List Of Users";
        $this->load->view('admin/users', $data);
    }
}
```

See the class name and `site_url('class/method')` and in your case `site_url('user/index')`

Comment: I am already getting the correct link.
http://localhost/wmss/index.php/admin/user/3
but still it is not working

Comment: Hi, could you please guide me, First Page link is not working?

Comment: what is the problem with it?